# T_object_operator error

Tags: php

I'm trying to understand why I am getting a unexpected T_object_operator error from this function and not sure why. It says its line 34 and on line 34 is the start of the function.

```
public function is_user_locked($user_data->lock_date)
{
    if ($user_data->lock_date !== '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
    {
        /* User is locked out */

        if (strtotime(gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', time())) < strtotime($user_data->lock_date))
        {
            /* User is still locked out */
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            /* User is no longer locked out */
            return FALSE;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You can't pass a parameter into a function that way. You can either pass in the appropriate object's property when you call it; or pass in the whole object and just use the relevant property inside the function

Comment: @andrewsi: "You can't pass a parameter into a function that way" --- it's not about passing *arguments*, it's about defining *parameters*. It's a parsing error, not a runtime error.

Comment: @zerkms - ah, I knew that; I just phrased it badly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`function is_user_locked($user_data->lock_date)` is not valid syntax, because you can't reference object properties as a function parameter *name*. Did you mean `function is_user_locked($user_data)`?

Comment: Honestly I don't know. I did not know you could not do that.

Comment: Could you point me to somewhere on the php.net site that talks about this.